# Javascript not working when URL have extra segment (CodeIgniter)

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have this Javascript for dependent dropdown, the problem is, it is not working if I put a segment after the  function name in the URL. For example:

`localhost/Folder/Class/function/data`

but if I only put `localhost/Folder/Class/function`, it does fully work.

I am using the 3rd URI segment for update function:

first i have this button on my datatable to show the information

`<a href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Employees/allinfo/'.$info->ID_NUM.'" class = "btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-left fa fa-question-circle" title="Show Personal Information"> Personal Info</a>`

then when the information shows, i have a update button

`<a href = '<?php echo base_url().'Employees/updatepersonalinfo/'.$data; ?>' class = 'btn btn-sm btn-info pull-right fa fa-edit'>&nbsp Update</a>`

the form now leads to this controller,

```
public function updatepersonalinfo(){

    $data['content'] = $this->Employees_Model->personalinfo();
    $data['content1'] = $this->Employees_Model->nationality();
    $data['content2'] = $this->Employees_Model->provinces();
    $data['content_view'] = 'Employees/edit_personalinfo';
    $this->templates->admin_template($data);


}
```

the personalinfo model has this query

`"SELECT * FROM employees WHERE ID_NUM = '".$this->uri->segment(3)."'";`

which will open this form

```
    <?php
      echo form_open('Employees/updatepinfo/'.$this->uri->segment(3));
    ?>
     *some input field
     <?php
      echo form_close();
    ?>
```

thats why i need the url segment..

Here is the Javascript I am using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("#PROV_ID").change(function() {
    var PROVID = {"PROVID" : $('#PROV_ID').val()};
    console.log(PROVID);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: PROVID,
      url: "<?php base_url(); ?>Employees/dependent_dropdown",

      success: function(data){
          var select = $('#CT_ID');
          select.html('');
          $.each(data, function(i, option){
              select.append("<option value='"+option.CT_ID+"'>"+option.CITY+"</option>");
          });
      }
     });
   });
 });
```

if i selected a PROVINCE it will give values to the next dropdown regarding the cities on that procince.(dependent dropdown) it will lead to this controller,

```
   public function dependent_dropdown()
   {
       if(isset($_POST['PROVID']))
       {

            $data = $_POST['PROVID'];
            $this->output
            ->set_content_type("application/json")
            ->set_output(json_encode($this->Employees_Model->getType($data)));
       }
   }
```

this perfectly works fine without the additional url segment. but does not work when i add another segment on the url. or even if i add only `/` to the url.

also this works perfectly fine earlier when i still dont have the dependent dropdown. to be clear that the problem is only on the dropdown jquery and the url.

Comment: where are you using the SELECT query? $this->uri->segment(3) should always have the same value regardless of what you have after ../function/data... IF you need this uri segment to update the db and you are doing this from model, it would be better to get this uri segment in the same javascript section and pass it as the data in ajax.

Comment: i am using it on my model. i am using it to get the value of the data i am updating

Comment: Try getting it in the view, in js .change function. You can have it as var id = '<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3);?>' and use this id in your ..../Employees/dependent_dropdown function to send it to model.

Comment: i dont think you get what im saying. im not using the javascript for getting the uri segment, i am using this(javascript) for the dependent dropdown. and i am using the uri segment for getting the value that i vill update

Comment: if you would most part of your view / model and controller code, that would be better.

Comment: Is `Folder` *root directory of your project* or directory in `APPPATH.'controllers'`? What is `$config['base_url']` value?

Comment: http://localhost/TLC_HR//

Comment: @CaptainRed i updated the question

Comment: @Tpojka i updated the question

Comment: @kev_m : Ques 1> What is the error you are getting?? ....Ques 2> Are you sure that the AJAX function 'public function dependent_dropdown()' is really getting called or you have an error before that?......Ques 3> I have not tried it, but are you sure you can use 'data: PROVID,' in your AJAX? Isn't it supposed to be data: {PROVID: PROVID}, so then you can use it in the controller function as $_POST['PROVID'] ??

Comment: it all works perfectly fine until i add a new segment]

Answer (score 0):

You can define your routes as shown below to make it work even if there is additional segments on the url. 
    localhost/Folder/Class/function/(:any)

Comment: how can i define it full

Comment: and on what class??

Comment: you have to define the above in routes.php. I want to know that are you trying to grab the uri segment in the modal or in the class.

Comment: Until the question is clearly understood, I cannot tell you the solution.

Comment: i updated the question so that you can understand more